# RegEx Group by Fixed Length

Tags: regex

Sample input:

```
19GMC TRNLLBLK
98CHY TK   GRN
02TOYO   4DWHI
21LAND     BLK
```

To help see what I'm trying to do:

```
19|GMC |TRN|LL|BLK
98|CHY |TK |  |GRN
02|TOYO|   |4D|WHI
21|LAND|   |  |BLK
```

Columns:

1. Always two digits
2. Always 3 letters followed by a space or 4 letters
3. Always all spaces, 2 letters followed by a space or 3 letters
4. Always all spaces or two characters
5. Always all spaces or three letters

I'm trying to use RegEx to select the non-white space characters within each "column".

The non-white characters would be part of a group (one for each column).

The white characters would be part of a non-selected group.

```
(?<DIG>\d{2})(?<MKE>\S{3,4})
```

I can't figure out how to create a non-selected group that figures out how many white spaces to select to prevent going into the "next column".

Comment: Which regex engine/programming language are you using?

Comment: Use alternation `|`, like `a|b` inside your groups.

Comment: I'm using VB.Net

Comment: If the columns are always fixed width, then you probably want to use a `Substring` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 5 capture groups:

```
^(\d{2})([A-Z]{3}[A-Z ])([A-Z]{2}[A-Z ]| +)([A-Z0-9]{2}| +)([A-Z]{3}| +)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d{2})` Group 1, match 2 digits
- `([A-Z]{3}[A-Z ])` Group 2, match 3 chars A-Z and either a char A-Z or a space
- `([A-Z]{2}[A-Z ]| +)` Group 3, match 2 chars A-Z and either a char A-Z or a space OR only spaces
- `([A-Z0-9]{2}| +)` Group 4, match 2 chars A-Z or 0-9 OR match only spaces
- `([A-Z]{3}| +)` Group 5, match 3 chars A-Z OR only spaces
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3e44HH/1).